# Swift - 'String' does not have a member named 'isEqualToString'

Tags: ios, swift

I got this error message when I trying to compare the string.

```
/Users/MNurdin/Documents/iOS/xxxxx/Controllers/ViewController.swift:46:12: 'String' does not have a member named 'isEqualToString'
```

My code

```
if mediaType.isEqualToString(kUTTypeImage as! String) {
            /**/

        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** didn't read your whole question. Added an example below.

`kUTTypeImage` is of type `CFString` which you can bridge into `NSString` or `String` directly. Using Swift's optional binding:

```
if let imageType = kUTTypeImage as? String where imageType == mediaType {
    // do something
}
```

Or more succintly:

```
if mediaType == kUTTypeImage as String {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

--> isEqualToString function not available in swift just comapre two string variables using this '=='(Double Equal to).

Try This:

```
if mediaType == KUTTypeImage
{
//Do your Stuff
}
```